# required String[] found String Java

Tags: java, string, encryption, rsa

Im trying to cycle through a byte array and decode it into a string, using RSA encryption, the encryption works with out an array but I am trying to make it usable for longer data, by encrypting each word of the string, but when doing this i get the error required String[] found String Java.

```
 // Decrypt the cipher text using the private key.
        inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(PRIVATE_KEY_FILE));
        final PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey) inputStream.readObject();
        String[][] decryptedText = new String[cipherText.length][];
        for (int i = 0; i < cipherText.length; i++) {
            **ERROR ON THIS LINE - required String[] found String Java**
         decryptedText[i] = decrypt(cipherText[i], privateKey);

        }
```

the decrypt method

```
  public static String decrypt(byte[] text, PrivateKey key) {
    byte[] dectyptedText = null;
    try {
        // get an RSA cipher object and print the provider
        final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
        // decrypt the text using the private key
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
        dectyptedText = cipher.doFinal(text);

    } catch (InvalidKeyException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | BadPaddingException |IllegalBlockSizeException | NoSuchPaddingException ex) {
    }

    return new String(dectyptedText);
}
```

Encrypt Method

```
public static byte[] encrypt(String text, PublicKey key) {
    byte[] cipherText = null;
    try {
        // get an RSA cipher object and print the provider
        final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
        // encrypt the plain text using the public key
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        cipherText = cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes());
    } catch (InvalidKeyException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | BadPaddingException | IllegalBlockSizeException | NoSuchPaddingException e) {
    }
    return cipherText;
}
```

Comment: [1] what error [2] encrypt method [3] cipherText

Comment: Edited the post there to show the encrypt method and what the error was

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is your `decryptedText` is a two dimensional array

```
 String[][] decryptedText = new String[cipherText.length][];
```

so this line

```
decryptedText[i] = decrypt(cipherText[i], privateKey);
```

must put an array to the `decryptedText`. You can change declaration of `decryptedText` to fix this

```
String[] decryptedText = new String[cipherText.length];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That works perfectly thank you, feel really dump for not working that out

Answer (score 0):

`decryptedText` is declared as

```
String[][] decryptedText
```

It's thus an array of arrays of Strings.

Thus, `decryptedText[i]` is the ith element in this array of arrays. It's thus an array of Strings. And you try to initialize it with the returned value of `decrypt()`, which doesn't return an array of Strings, but a String. Hence the error.

I don't understand why you have a 2D array, and not simply an array of Strings.